# All SE profiles should indicate if a user is currently suspended on any other sites to 20k+ users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page, account-suspension

In the past I have found troublesome users and upon visiting their SE profiles I have found that they are already suspended on 1 or 2 other SE sites, however if I want to find this out I have to go to all of their SE profiles and they may have very many profiles so it may be hard, or at least, time consuming to look through them all to see for current suspensions.

When I say troublesome users, it may just be users who are acting slightly strangely who could be trolls, but might also not be, so it would be very useful if by going to one of their SE profiles I could see if they have been suspended on any other SE sites (it could display how many sites and also which one(s)).

As there will probably be objection to all users being able to see if a user is suspended on any of the sites they are on, then perhaps this could be a feature only enabled for **10k+ or 20k+** users whom it would be useful to to help moderate the site and spot trolls before things get out of hand.

Comment: Public Shame Exhibition™ -- I kinda disagree.

Comment: @IͶΔ: I understand what you mean, but the notice is shown on the site they are suspended on, and they have been suspended for good reason, so if they are bad would it not be good for other users of other sites to know about this? At least 10k+ or 20k+ users so it's not like you say a "Public Share Exhibition" for everyone to see...

Comment: I did say why. If we publicly shame users who may be sorry because they're suspended, we're actively saying "get lost. You're not wanted here" Suspended users sometimes turn out to be positive members after they've learned their lesson.

Comment: @IͶΔ: But it then might at least be useful for uses with high rep who have been around for a long time to be able to spot users who've been bad on other sites and are currently paying for it.

Comment: Suspension is the punishment @Paranoid. Put yourself in the shoes of the suspended user and see what the problem with a "this user is banned on X.SE" is. Also, such a banner wouldn't encourage any constructive conversation with the user. No one is forcing you to converse with anyone. If you sense you should disengage, do it. There's no need for a "don't talk to this guy".

Comment: @IͶΔ: I understand what you mean, but why would it be bad to at least allow users who have 20k+ rep and have been here for a long time and are mature enough not to abuse the feature to have it? Like the moderator tools we get access to at 10k+ and viewing deleted questions etc, that could also be seen in a negative way if someone deletes something because it says something bad and they don't want to be public and then 10k+ users can view it. How is this any different?

Comment: This isn't about abuse or anything. It's just that it would be actively discouraging a constructive exchange. Imagine that I had a "this is a jerk" sign on my forehead in the beginning of this conversation. How would you feel about me? If I had a question, would I have the same chances of being helped than before?

Comment: related: [Let's disallow nominations from people who've been suspended in the past year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274114/165773)

Comment: I am not really sure about how I feel with this suggestion. From one side, the whole "don't mark the user seem a reasonable though. From another one, I am asking myself why I got on the user profile page in the first place if I didn't feel something odd was going on. Anyway, this *could* be useful in case of spam-related suspensions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a user is a network-wide menace, site moderators should be able to recognise that<sup>†</sup> and get a community moderator or SE staff member involved. Do I wish this was easier for moderators to automate this process (ie for spam), sure. Do I think it would have any meaningful effect on the *very few* people who troll many sites? No, not at all.

I think the problem people are having with this suggestion is that there's very little value in prominently advertising users' past behaviour. Really, it doesn't matter if somebody posted a load of rubbish three years ago. They might have grown up. Even if it's an active issue on another site, it doesn't automatically mean they're bad news. You could break the rules on Stack Overflow but be a great Ask Ubuntu user.

Judge people on what they do on your site. Don't hound them around the network.

---

<sup>†</sup> Like anyone, mods can look at a user's network profiles and work out which have been suspended. They can investigate with that site's moderators in the moderator's communal chat room. This is *so* rare that we'd only need it when we're already taking action for a local infraction. There's no value in just showing current network suspensions to everybody.

Comment: A side-note: a person with a modest command of JavaScript can concoct a userscript to poll user profiles looking for suspension notes. However, this would definitely result in too many queries to SE servers and subsequent suspension of the curious 'un. Vote for the answer, not the person.