# Election bug: removed candidates can rejoin the election!

Tags: bug, election

So I am an active contributor of Stack Overflow in Russian and I joined the election this year. Because of my ban on MSE (damn it! ;)) my candidacy was removed from the election. But I found out that I can rejoin the election!

I'm gonna add some images:

> [image: I'm on election again]

> [image]

I guess it is a bug, isn't it? Or is it the... the... ***SECOND CHANCE*** ? ?? ;)

**P.S** I tried to add my candidacy just to test SE for a bug. *Wha?*
*Wha?* **NO!** I'm not cheatin' ;)

Comment: This seems like the same underlying bug as [Suspended user shouldn't be able to run in an election on the site they're suspended on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312275/suspended-user-shouldnt-be-able-to-run-in-an-election-on-the-site-theyre-suspe).