# Use user card instead of flair on elections

Tags: feature-request, election, profile-picture, flair

I'd like to see the user card, as displayed on the post, instead of the flair, when choosing candidates in the election.

One problem is that if a candidate moderator changes their name and/or profile picture during the election phase of the election, their old flair is cached and shows for quite a while.

This may cause confusion, as the name and picture don't correspond with the name and picture shown in their post.

Example screenshot:

[image]

Additionally, if we'd show the user cards, that would make comparing your current choices to other candidates much more easy, as the candidate score of your current choices would show next to the one you're considering when scrolling.

It would also make the UI more consistent.

<sub>Note: this post was posted as a bug request first, but as noted by Animuson in the comments, it should be a feature request instead</sub>

Comment: Related: "[Do not allow moderator candidates to change their user names during elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350918/282094)".

Comment: No repro on FF Android: [both avatars are the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pjox.jpg), as of a minute ago.

Comment: This isn't a bug. We just insert a user's flair into the side menu when you've voted for the person, and that image is very heavily cached at multiple places. It intentionally takes a long time to update when there have been changes. However, I've always thought it weird to insert a flair image there instead of something like a duplicated user card from the page. Perhaps request that as a new feature?

Comment: @animuson I've edited the post into a feature request as per your suggestion