# Include link to the mod agreement when collecting nominations

Tags: feature-request, moderators, election, nominations

Apparently some sites or some pages include it already. I am specifically referring to this page:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/9?tab=nomination

It's important for moderator candidates to understand what they are getting into, and they [might not think to look for the moderator agreement in the help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/9?tab=nomination#comment618242_188341).

We should **consistently** include a link to the current moderator agreement that every moderator must accept somewhere in the informational text about nominations and what a moderator does.

I think increased visibility of the policies moderators must follow would be good for both potential nominees and voters.

Comment: I don't know if this is new or if it's SO-specific, but there's a link to the moderator agreement on the [election page of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/election) whose nomination phase just started.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine: It looks like that's something the SO mods in particular edited into their version of the election page starting in 2020. Looking at [another current election on The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/9) (or looking back at any site that's recently held its first mod election and thus had its election info blurb generated automatically, such as [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/1)), it doesn't look like it's a default part of the "blurb" included on election pages.

Comment: I can't test it but I *thought* we put a link to the mod agreement on the nomination page or the modal when someone clicks to nominate in the election... I don't have a "nominate" button, though, so I can't check. :P

Comment: @Catija Thanks :) … I think it would be helpful to have it available prior to making the decision to self-nominate.

Comment: I agree. I think there was one time when a mod won an election but resigned immediately after because they disagreed with one aspect of the moderator agreement. As the election didn't have enough nominees to be competitive after removing said user, making it impossible to simply call the one candidate who lost, they had to schedule another election to get their replacement.

Answer (score 2):

A good idea. But it's already been done.

It's in the Stack Overflow election text (see below). Although that's slightly different than the election text on other sites, I remember seeing that line when I ran for mod (at least once).

> Generally, moderators should have the following qualities:
>
> - patient and fair
> - leads by example
> - shows respect for their fellow community members in their actions and words
> - open to some light but firm moderation to keep the community on track, and resolve uncommon disputes and exceptions
>
> For the Stack Overflow election, candidates **must** have all the following badges:
> [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty), [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white), [Deputy](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1002/deputy), [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/901/convention)
>
> ...and also [cannot have been suspended during the past year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).
>
> Furthermore, all moderators **must** abide by the [moderator agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement).

Comment: Where did you copy that text from please?

Comment: It looks like this link is something the SO mods in particular edited into their version of the election page starting in 2020. Looking at [another current election on The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/9) (or looking back at any site that's recently held its first mod election and thus had its election info blurb generated automatically, such as [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/1)), it doesn't look like it's a default part of the "blurb" included on election pages.

Comment: @V2Blast yeah, I was not aware until recently that mods (not only staff) can edit the text on election page, including the past one.